# Unable to send objects as payload data while making an Fetch API request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch-api, mern

I have a react frontend and node backend, I am fetching a list of objects from an external API using Axios and then trying to pass it to my node backend. The issue is that the node backend is not able to receive this payload data on the backend, req.body returns an empty object.
To debug, I've seen what happens in the network tab, and have observed that the payload data just returns the data type instead of the actual data as shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuowe.png)
Here is what my front-end code looks like:

```
let faqlist = "";
// fetching data from one api
await axiosinstance
  .get(
    "https://linktotheapi/api/faq"
  )
  .then((res) => {
    faqlist = res.data;

    console.log("This is faqlist", faqlist);
    console.log(typeof faqlist);
    // passing the data fetched from 1st api to node/express backend.
    fetch("/create-page", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: faqlist,
    });
    
  });}
```

Comment: What does console.log("This is faqlist", faqlist); print ? Can you provide just an small bit of console log?

Comment: @subodhkalika, on the front-end it does give me the actual array of objects.

Comment: I guess the parameter should be payload  instead of body.

Comment: it's documented that the `body` must match the `content-type` of the request - your content-type is `application/json` ... therefore, applying the aforementioned rule, `body` should be JSON

Comment: Axios does the JSON <-> object conversion automatically and fetch doesn't, so using both is inviting confusion.  If you use axios to post, you can just send the parsed result of the get (and axios will re-encode it as a string).

Comment: @gvmani - fetch does not recognise a property on the init parameter called `payload` - you can't just make up properties and expect them to work

Comment: please don't update your question with a new question once your original question is solved ... start a new question for the new issue

Comment: @Bravo, noted! This is the first time I'm using StackOverflow so was unaware of the rules.

Comment: It's not a "rule" as such - but focused questions are better. I mean, someone went to the trouble to write an answer, and now it looks like they only answered part of your question! How can you accept that answer if it doesn't answer your added question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `stringify` the array of objects before sending. Use `JSON.stringify`

```
const x = [{ x: 1 }, { x: 2 }];
  fetch("https://httpbin.org/post", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(x)
  });
```

Comment: It worked on the front-end, now I do get the actual object list on the payload when I view it in the networks tab, but still get an empty object when I console.log(req.body) on the backend.

Comment: @lazypotato8821 - you're sending `json` to a `urlencoded` body parser - can you see the problem yet? It's like ordering a meal in Japanese to a person that only understands German

Comment: @Bravo, I am new to node/express ecosystem so apologies for asking but what should be done instead ?

Comment: include a Japanese speaking person to receive the request ... :p (hint: `bodyParser` supports multiple body content-types)

Comment: @lazypotato8821
Have you used  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));   or for newer versions 
app.use(express.json()); on backend ?

Comment: @subodhkalika, thanks a lot. Replacing app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})) with app.use(express.json()); worked.